# Unfilled "self" Parameter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to code a game and I need a button (Button A) to primarily be off than when a different button (Button B) is pressed Button A turns on here is what I  tried so far

```
def click():   # defines the press of Button B
    p1name = P1.get()
    p2name = P2.get()
    namethanks = 'thank you "' + p1name + ' " you are player 1 (X) \n and thank you "' + p2name +'" you are player 2 (O)'
    namesubmission.insert(END, namethanks)
    realgametime.configure(state=DISABLED,)
```

then this is the code defining button A

```
realgametime(window, text="play the game", width=13, command=play, bg=bgcolour, fg=fgcolour, state=DISABLED) .grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)  # button A
```

then this is the error:

[image]

please help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you used

```
realgametime(window, text="play the game", width=13, command=play, bg=bgcolour, fg=fgcolour, state=DISABLED) .grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)  # button A
```

to create the button, but you did not assign it to any variable.

When you called `realgametime.configure`, you were calling the method on the class itself, not on the button you instantiated.

Trying something like this:

```
buttonA = realgametime(window, text="play the game", width=13, command=play, bg=bgcolour, fg=fgcolour, state=DISABLED) .grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
buttonA.configure(state=DISABLED)
```